# Why isn't std::array::size static?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

The size of [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is known at compile time, but the `size` member function isn't static. Is there any reason for that? It's slightly inconvenient not to be able to calculate the size without instantiating an object. (Well, I know about `std::tuple_size` specialization, but it doesn't work for classes derived from `std::array`.)

Comment: " but it doesn't work for classes derived " why it does work?

Comment: This might be well suited for the [std-discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!forum/std-discussion) newsgroup.

Comment: @Suma Selection of specialization doesn't respect inheritance. You have to add a `tuple_size` specialization for every derived class.

Comment: Deriving from `std::array` doesn't sound like a terribly good idea in the first place.

Comment: @ComicSansMS Why not? It's POD, you can't get more harmless than that. (Although, writing `tuple_size` specializations is certainly a red flag.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter As with other STL containers, `std::array` is more of [a value-typeish](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/val-vs-ref-semantics.html) type. The absence of a virtual destructor alone makes it hard to use sensibly in polymorphic contexts. I cannot think of a single use-case where I wouldn't be better off using composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: @ComicSansMS So don't use it in polymorphic contexts ;) . Inheritance has various odd uses in C++.

Comment: You can actually use it with `std::shared_ptr` in a polymorphic way. `std::shared_ptr` will take care of deletion through pointer.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Can you name one that is not better solved by composition? This is not a rhetoric question, I tried constructing one, but failed. If you know a legitimate use case, I'd honestly like to hear about it.

Comment: @ComicSansMS Apparently, the use case is when you want to retain the features of the base class and add some new, i.e. an "is a" relationship. Composition is not so convenient here because it incurs unnecessary boilerplate code clutter because: you have to forward all the functions of the base class, write copy and assignment operators etc.

Comment: @lizarisk An is-a relationship (imho) implies a polymorphic context, so I'd not use that term for this scenario. I do see your point of wanting to create a 'special kind of array' without having to duplicate all of the interface functions. But this boils down to using inheritance purely for code-reuse, which (again, imho) is a smell. In case of `std::array` it's debatable whether the savings in boilerplate code make up for the tight coupling introduced by the inheritance, but I see your point. Thanks for taking the time to explain.

Comment: @ComicSansMS What lizarkisk said, and also without inheritance you have to rely on perfect forwarding to bring the wrapped interface out to the wrapping class. That didn't exist before C++11, and "perfect" is actually a misnomer. Also there's the empty base optimization. Using non-public inheritance for these things eliminates the risk of the user abusing polymorphism.

Comment: More importantly, why isn't it `const`?

Comment: @AnT Bug. Fixed in C++14. Was a `constexpr` though.

Comment: @AnT In C++11 `constexpr` implies `const`, so it actually was `const`.

Comment: @nwp: Hm... Yes, you are right, it impli*ed* `const` in C++11 (but not in C++14).

Answer (score 16):

Since C++11 you can use `std::tuple_size` on `std::array` to obtain the size as a compile time constant.  See

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/tuple_size

Comment: As the OP pointed out, it doesn't work for classes derived from `std::array`.

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Answer (score 15):

**There is no good reason for that.** In fact, [`boost::array<T, N>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/array.html), the precursor of `std::array<T,N>`, actually defines `static size_t size(){return N;}` (although a modern more useful version should use `constexpr` also).

I agree with the OP that this is an unfortunate omission and underexplotaition of the language features.

**Problem**

I faced this problem before and the logic leads to a couple of solutions. The OP situation is the following: you have a class that derives from `std::array` and you need to access to the size at compile time.

```
#include<array>

template<class T...>
struct myarray : std::array< something that depends on T... >{
    ... very cool functions...
};
```

and later you have

```
template<class Array, size_t N = ???>
functionOnArrayConcept(Array const& a){...}
```

Where you need to know `N` at compile time.

As it is now, there is no code `???` that you can write that works both for `std::array` and `myarray`, because `std::tuple_size<myarray<...>>` will not work.

**Solution**

(this was suggested by @T.C. here [Access maximum template depth at compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227436/access-maximum-template-depth-at-compile) . I am just copying it here.)

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
auto array_size_impl(const std::array<T, N>&) 
    -> std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>;

template<class Array>
using array_size = decltype(array_size_impl(std::declval<const Array&>()));

template<class Array>
constexpr auto static_size() -> decltype(array_size<Array>::value){
    return array_size<Array>::value;
}
template<class Array>
constexpr auto static_size(Array const&) -> decltype(static_size<Array>()){
    return static_size<Array>();
}
```

Now you can use it as this:

```
template<class Array, size_t N = static_size<Array>()>
functionOnArrayConcept(Array const& a){...}
```

If you are using `std::tuple_size` already, unfortunately (I think) you need to specialize `std::tuple_size` for each of your derived classes:

```
namespace std{
    template<class... T> // can be more complicated if myarray is not parametrized by classes only
    struct tuple_size<myclass<T...>> : integral_constant<size_t, static_size<myclas<T...>>()>{};
}
```

(In my opinion this is caused by another mistake in the STL design that `std::tuple_size<A>` doesn't have the default `template<class A> struct tuple_size : A::size(){}`.)

---

> The solutions beyond this point are near obsolete compared to @T.C.
>   solution described above. I'll keep them here for reference only.

<s>**Solution 1 (idiomatic)**</s>

If the function is decoupled from you class you have to use `std::tuple_size` because that is the only standard way of accessing the size of `std::array` at compile time. Therefore you have to do this, 1) provide a specialization of `std::tuple_size` and if you can control `myclass`, 2) `std::array` doesn't have `static size()` but your derived class could (that simplifies the solution).

So, this can be a pretty general solution within the framework of STD, that consists in the specialization of `std::tuple_size`.
(Unfortunately providing specialization in `std::` sometimes is the only way to make real generic code. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std)

```
template<class... T>
struct myarray : std::array<...something that depends on T...>{
    ... very cool functions...
    static constexpr size_t size(){return std::tuple_size<std::array<...something that depends on T...>>::value;}
};

namespace std{
    // specialization of std::tuple_size for something else that `std::array<...>`.
    template<class... T> // can be more complicated if myarray is not parametrized by classes only
    struct tuple_size<myclass<T...>> : integral_constant<size_t, myclass<T...>::size()>{};
}

// now `functionOnArrayConcept` works also for `myarray`.
```

(`static size_t size()` can be called differently, and there may be other ways to deduce the size of the base of `myarray` without adding any static function to `size`.)

**Note**

In the compilers I tried the following trick doesn't work. If this worked, the whole discussion would be less important, because `std::tuple_size` wouldn't be so necessary.

```
template<class ArrayConcept, size_t N = ArrayConcept{}.size()> // error "illegal expression", `std::declval<ArrayConcept>()` doesn't work either.
functionOnArrayConcept(ArrayConcept const& a){...}
```

**Conceptualization**

Due to this shortcoming in the implementation (or specification?) of `std::array` by which the only way to extract the compile time `size` is through `std::tuple_size`. Then `std::tuple_size` is *conceptually* part of the necessary interface of `std::array`. Therefore when you inherit from `std::array` you have also "inherit" `std::tuple_size` in some sense. And unfortunately you need to do this for further derivations. This is the concept behind this answer.

<s>**Solution 2 (a GNU hack)**</s>

If you are using GNU's STD library (that includes `gcc` and `clang`), there is a hack that can be used without adding any code, and that is by using the `_M_elems` member which is of (member) type `::_AT_Type::_Type`  (a.k.a. type `T[N]`) of `std::array<T, N>`.

This function will effectively behave like a static function `::size()` (except that it cannot be used for instances of an object) of `std::array` or any type derived from `std::array`.

```
std::extent<typename ArrayType::_AT_Type::_Type>::value
```

which can be wrapped into:

```
template<class ArrayType>
constexpr size_t array_size(){
    return std::extent<typename ArrayType::_AT_Type::_Type>::value
}
```

This work because the member type `_AT_Type::_Type` is inherited. (I wonder why GNU left this implementation detail `public`. Another omission?)

<s>**Solution 3 (a portable hack)**</s>

Finally, a solution using template recursion one can figure out what is the dimension of the base `std::array`.

```
template<class Array, size_t N=0, bool B = std::is_base_of<std::array<typename Array::value_type, N>, Array>::value>
struct size_of : size_of<Array, N + 1, std::is_base_of<std::array<typename Array::value_type, N+1>, Array>::value>{};

template<class Array, size_t N>
struct size_of<Array, N, true> : std::integral_constant<size_t, N>{};

// this is a replacement for `static Array::size()`    
template<class Array, size_t N = size_of<Array>::value>
constexpr size_t static_size(){return N;}

// this version can be called with an object like `static Array::size()` could
template<class Array, size_t N = size_of<Array>::value>  
constexpr size_t static_size(Array const&){return N;}
```

This is how one will get:

```
struct derived : std::array<double, 3>{};

static_assert( static_size<std::array<double, 3>>() == 3 );
static_assert( static_size<derived>() == 3 );
constexpr derived d;
static_assert( static_size(d) == 3 );
```

If this function is called with some type unrelated to `std::array`, it will give a recursion error. If you want a "soft" error instead, you have to add the specialization.

```
template<class Array>
struct size_of<Array, 250, false> {};
```

where `250` stands for a large number but smaller than the recursion limit. (I don't know how to get this number automatically, I only know the the recursion limit in my compiler is `256`.)

Answer (score 1):

It can indeed be static, however, this would break "container" interface which won't play well with other generic algorithms that do expect containers to have `size()` member function. There is nothing to worry about, though, as `std::array::size()` is a `constexpr` function, so there is absolutely no overhead associated with it.

UPDATE:

Mr. Jrok have pointed out that one can call static member functions with "normal" syntax. Below is an example when it won't:

```
#include <array>

struct array {
    static unsigned int size()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

template <typename T>
static auto do_stuff(T& data) -> decltype(data.size())
{
    typedef decltype(data.size()) size_type;
    size_type (T::*size_calc)() const = &T::size;
    size_type n = 0;
    for (size_type i = 0, e = (data.*size_calc)(); i < e; ++i)
        ++n;
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    // Below is fine:
    std::array<int, 5> data { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    do_stuff(data);

    // This, however, won't work as "size()" is not a member function.
#if 0
    array fake;
    do_stuff(fake);
#endif
}
```

Comment: You can call static member functions with 'normal' syntax, so how would that break interface?

Comment: How does that break a container interface?

Comment: Good point about how some generic code could fail with a static member function, however the actual container requirements don't require containers to allow member pointers to `size()`; All that's required is that the expression `a.size()` work, and a static member function fulfills that requirement.

Comment: `// This, however, won't work as "size()" is not a member function.` Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: The code example above is confusing because it actually (should) works. There are other contexts in which the OP use causes problems. (not this one).

Comment: This answer makes a good point, however, if you look carefully, the original `std::array::size()` is not `const` (!). Which kinda defeats the idea of compatibility with other containers.

Comment: The whole thing is confusing. `std::array::size` is `const` (since C++14) `http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size`. The point is that it should be `static constexpr size_t size()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`array::size` is `constexpr`, so unless the stored type has a constructor or destructor, the operation `array_t().size()` is very unlikely to have any runtime effect. You can embed it in a template argument to ensure it doesn't. It does otherwise *look* like runtime code, though.

I think that it's nonstatic simply for uniformity with other containers. For example, you can form a pointer-to-member-function to it. Discovering the true rationale of anything often takes tough research, though. It could be that the authors never thought of it.

The other thing that comes to mind is that some special functions such as `operator () ()` cannot be static, so any opportunistic application of static can only be piecemeal. Generic problems are better solved in uniform fashion, even if it means changing the core language.

Comment: `array_t().size()` would certainly have a runtime overhead due to initialization of a temporary array.

Comment: @lizarisk It's all constexpr. Although the array initialization conceptually happens, the object gets thrown away and there's never a need to actually store it anywhere, as long as it's POD. For non-POD stored types, yes, you would see the constructor and/or destructor run.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Can it really be optimized if the value_type doesn't have a constexpr constructor?

Comment: @user2079303: From the first line of this answer: `so unless the stored type has a constructor or destructor`

Comment: @Potatoswatter, I've checked the assembly, and it does have a runtime effect at least with -O0.

Comment: @lizarisk That doesn't really count. Constexpr functions (outside contexts like template arguments and array bounds) are in general not guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time, so that they can be artificially run at runtime for the sake of debugging.

Comment: More importantly array_t().size() doesn't work as template parameter (when I tried at least.) See the note in my answer.

Comment: "It could be that the authors never thought of it." . If the authors based their design on `boost::array` they must have thought about it, because in `boost::array` `size()` is `static`.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-declare a same-typed empty `std::array` (which should get optimized out) and take the size of that.  For example:

```
// Pretend this is an expensive initialization; e.g., a function return value.
std::array<char, 0x123> some_array{1,2,3};
using type_of_some_array = decltype(some_array);

// Find the size without accessing the array.
auto constexpr size_of_some_array = type_of_some_array().size();

std::cout << size_of_some_array << std::endl;
```

compiles to:

```
00000000004006f0 <main>:
  4006f0:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  4006f4:       be 23 01 00 00          mov    $0x123,%esi
  4006f9:       bf 60 10 60 00          mov    $0x601060,%edi
  4006fe:       e8 ad ff ff ff          callq  4006b0 <_ZNSo9_M_insertImEERSoT_@plt>
  ...
```

[No issues found when using `size_of_some_array` as a template parameter: which was counter-alluded to in the comments on @Potatoswatter's answer.]

Answer (score -1):

Note that the Microsoft Visual C++ doesn't currently support constexpr (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx), so the following valid code won't work:

```
    array<int,3> dog;
    array<double, dog.size( )> cat;
```

The following class provides a compile time static variable:

```
/**
* hack around MSVC's 2012 lack of size for const expr
*/
template <typename T, int N>
struct vcarray : public std::array<T,N> {
    static const size_t ArraySize= N;
};
```

which can be used as:

```
vcarray<double,3> cat;
vcarray<double,cat.ArraySize> dog;
```

Answer (score -5):

In my opinion it does not make sense to make the `size` member function `static` insofar as it provides no added value. It is possible to make it `static`, but you gain nothing from it.

The way the `array` class is designed, you can query the size of a given `array` object without explicitly knowing/remembering its exact type (which includes its size) at that location where you need the size. This is a convenience, and it removes the opportunity to make copy/edit errors. You can write code like this:

```
std::array<int, 5> blah;
// 50 lines of code
do_something_with(blah.size()); // blah knows its size
```

As you can see, at the location where I'm consuming the array's size, I don't actually remember what it was, but my code will work anyway, regardless of what the value actually is, and regardless whether maybe one day I change the array's type to be a different size.
Since the `size` function merely returns a template parameter, the compiler can trivially prove that the return value is a compile-time constant and optimize accordingly too (the function is also `constexpr`, so you can also use the return value as template parameter or enumeration).

Now what will be different if we make the `size` member function `static`?

If `size` was a `static` function, you could *still* use the static member function in the exact same way (that is, on an object instance, in a "not static way"), but that would be "cheating". After all, this is something that already works anyway, whether the member is `static` or not.
Further, you now have the possibility of invoking the member function *without an object instance*.  While this seems like a good thing at first glance *it really is no advantage at all* for the `array` class template (...where the returned size is a template parameter).

In order to call a member function without an object (that is, in a "`static` member function way"), you must properly qualify the function with the class name and its proper template parameters.
In other words, you must write something like:

```
std::array<int, 5> blah;
// 50 lines of code
do_something_with(std::array<int,5>::size()); // I must tell size what to return
```

Now what have we gained from calling the `size` function? Nothing at all. In order to call the function, we needed to provide the correct template parameters, *which includes the size*.

That means no more and no less than that we must supply the information that we wish to query. Calling the function doesn't tell us anything we didn't already know.

Comment: Static members can be called with normal syntax on the instance, you don't have to provide the type.

Comment: The benefit is the ability to use it without an object instance, apparently. `virtual` is irrelevant here as it changes a lot of things and adds overhead. `static` doesn't really change anything significant as I can see.

Comment: (reworded answer, deleted comments)

Comment: The benefit would be what @lizarisk said, but more importantly that you can evaluate `Array::size()` at compile time. Many times a function acting on `std::array` (or derived classes, or conceptually similar classes) is written as `template<class Array> fun(Array const& a){...}`. If you need to know its size at compile time then you have a problem.

Comment: @alfC: Well yes, but you _must already know_ the size so you can evaluate `size()`. Which makes it kind of pointless (well not really pointless, but syntactic sugar that makes code easier). The array's size is a template parameter, it must be known at compile time before you even think about invoking any of its members. It arguably makes writing a template function that accepts _any type_ having a `size` member and that needs a size for some reason easier, but no new knowledge is really gained, it's only things you already know.

Comment: I am not saying that the (compile constant) `size` can not be deduced somehow. I am saying that it cannot be deduced generically for all classes that fulfill the concept of an array. Supposed I tell you have a class `myclass` inherits from some `std::array<double, N>` where N can be anything. How do you know at compile-time what is the size of the base class of `myclass`? (See my answer for details.)