# Access maximum template depth at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, clang++, compiler-options

In a certain compilation I need to play around with the option `-ftemplate-depth=N` that specifies the maximum template recursion.

**Is it possible to access the value of the maximum template depth from the program?**

I am interested in `gcc` or `clang`.

`$ c++ -ftemplate-depth=128 main.cpp`

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){
  std::cout << MAX_TEMPLATE_RECURSION << std::endl; // hypothetical name
}
```

Comment: ...and that's how template meta meta programming started class. Any questions?

Comment: @JerryCoffin, Correct! In case your are curious, this is to hack around a problem in STL, that is that `std::array` doesn't have a `static size()` function. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35988594/225186. Currently I have to hard code the max recursion limit.

Comment: Can't you use template argument deduction to determine the size? `template <typename> struct array_size; template <typename T, size_t N> struct array_size<std::array<T, N>> { static const size_t result = N; };`?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. You don't need "try every possible size" to handle classes derived from `std::array`, unless perhaps you want to allow an inaccessible/ambiguous base. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3c9e3ee78d9509d

Comment: @templatetypedef, the problem with that is that it cannot be applied to derived classes.

Comment: @T.C. Thank you, I think you made my other answer obsolete. (I suspected that it would be a XY problem, but I was curious about the max depth anyway.)

Comment: @T.C. I corrected my other answer with your solution.

Comment: Where does the question mention std::array, or have this part of the question been edited out?

Comment: @user877329, the discussion diverged into std::array because I was trying to solve this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35988594/225186 . It turns out that this was not needed to solve that problem, but technically the question doesn't have an answer and probably it doesn't have a standard answer.