# Why is std::array<T,N>::size() not declared static?

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, stdarray

Using C++20 MinGW and MSVC, I encountered - at least for me - unexpected behaviour.

Writing this boiled down and seemingly senseless `static_assert` code compiled fine:

```
void functionArray(std::array<uint8_t, 2> const data)
{
    static_assert(2 == data.size());
}
```

Whereas this code did not:

```
void functionArray(std::array<uint8_t, 2> const & data)
{
    static_assert(2 == data.size());
}
```

> error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant

A solution with the current C++ capabilities seems to be to use [`std::tuple_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/tuple_size)'s special overload for `std::array`:

```
void functionArray(std::array<uint8_t, 2> const & data)
{
    static_assert(2 == std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference<decltype(data)>::type>{});
}
```

MSVC implements `std::array<T,N>::size()` as:

```
template <class _Ty, size_t _Size>
class array { // fixed size array of values
public:
    _NODISCARD constexpr size_type size() const noexcept {
        return _Size;
    }
};
```

Why is `(& std::array<T,N>)::size()` not evaluated at compile time?

Is it because the reference to a `std::array` instance itself is not a `constexpr` variable, and so the implicit `this` in the member function call prevents compile time evaluation (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14248310/14973801))?

Why is `std::array<T,N>::size()` not declared `static`?

The following example shows that this would solve the problem described above:

```
#include <cstddef>

template <size_t N>
struct Blub
{
    static constexpr size_t size()
    {
        return N;
    }
};

void blubFunction(Blub<4> const & blub)
{
    static_assert(4 == blub.size());
}
```

Comment: I am using MSVC and the `.size()` method is implemented as the following: `_NODISCARD constexpr size_type size() const noexcept { return _Size; }` where `_Size` is the template argument. However I still can't compile your example since `data` can't be used in a constant expression.

Comment: Because the authors wanted to make such code legal `std::array<uint8_t, 4> arr; functionArray(arr);` regardless of the size of the parameter `std::array<uint8_t, 2> const & data`. IDK why they did not accept it. The implementation of `std::array::size()` looks like left from that proposal. But as @Joel mentioned, this is already changed.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to the actual implementation. So the problem I encountered seems to stem from a different problem. Thus I changed my question somewhat to reflect this.

Comment: @273K Passing a `std::array<uint8_t, 4> arr;` into `functionArray` [after removing the `static_assert`] did not compile: _error C2664: 'void functionArray(const std::array<uint8_t,2>)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::array<uint8_t,4>' to 'const std::array<uint8_t,2>'_ Did I understand your first sentence wrong?

Comment: I'm confused by the problem you're encountering. If the constant is "hard-coded" in, there's no need to check against it. If it's a template instead, you already have it without having to call `std::array<T, N>::size`.

Comment: *Did I understand your first sentence wrong?* No, you didn't. They wanted to make this code compiled, but some technical difficulties stopped them.

Comment: @Vivick In the actual code, the `2` in the `static_assert(2 == ...)` stems from a `sizeof(globalData)` where `static uint8_t const globalData[2]{...};` is defined globally at the top of the cpp-file. As I wanted to prevent others from changing `globalData` without also changing my `arrayFunction` I wanted to introcude an additional check right here in `arrayFunction`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Asking about why a certain design choice was used over another is a hard question to get an answer to. If I was to throw in my guess it's because what all the other containers in the standard library does/has. I don't know if making it static could have caused any issues when dealing with a `std::array` in a generic template context, but maybe?

Comment: @JohannesWilde    Your response to vivick doesn't quite make sense to me (notwithstanding that I think the question you asked is interesting).    Even if `static_assert(2 == data.size())` worked, it wouldn't force a diagnostic if the dimension of `globalData` was changed.   Why not `static_assert(sizeof(globalData)/sizeof(*globalData) == 2)`?

Comment: Related or dup? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21936507/why-isnt-stdarraysize-static

Comment: There's also the fact that maybe not a lot of people know that you can call static member functions on an instance of a class. Plus making it static wouldn't change the fact that the function isn't `constexpr` or `consteval` so the parameter couldn't be treated as `constexpr`-usable

Comment: Your `Blub` example is just as problematic as the original `std::array` example - you still are evaluating a reference. This is resolved by [P2280](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2280r4.html) as a defect against C++20.

Comment: @273K Are you saying that the original idea was that you could pass an array of size 4 to a reference to an array of size 2, and calling `size` would give you 4? That can only be the case if `size` were to be a virtual function, or were implemented using a virtual function. Did the original design really have virtual `size`?